# SQL Query error with Join

Tags: sql

When I try to execute this SQL query, I get an error and I don't know how to correct it

```
select  * 
from    pg_specialites_annees   pgs  
where   pgs.NOM_FR like '%tets%' 
left join pg_specialites_parametres pgsp on pgsp.ID_SPECIALITE = pgs.ID_SPECIALITE;
```

When I remove the `LIKE` it works, but I need a specific row.

Please help me, I don't know how to do it.  I want to show some details for a specific row in table from another table.

Comment: SQL expects statements to be in the following order: `SELECT`, `FROM`, `JOIN`, `ON`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, `ORDER BY`  which is not the same order as execution.

Comment: The complete and correct syntax for a select statement is documented in the manual of your DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LEFT JOIN` needs to come before the `WHERE`:

```
Select      * 
From        pg_specialites_annees       pgs  
Left Join   pg_specialites_parametres   pgsp    on  pgsp.ID_SPECIALITE = pgs.ID_SPECIALITE
Where       pgs.NOM_FR Like '%tets%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your `where` clause after the `join` clause :

```
select * from pg_specialites_annees pgs  
        left join pg_specialites_parametres pgsp on pgsp.ID_SPECIALITE = pgs.ID_SPECIALITE;
        where  pgs.NOM_FR like '%tets%'
```